# getting Out of memory on a 18662412-byte allocation error while load 15 image

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i'm going to show the image in my CardView via recyclerview. there is 15 image totally 15mg size. when I run the app on genymotion emulator(custom phone 4.1.1 Api16 specification) I get the out of memory error.
the error is on this line:

```
foodViewHolder.txtImage.setImageResource(food.getConverted_image());
```

this is my adapter

```
package com.example.android.dezcook;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Android on 6/11/2016.
 */

public class Food_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Food_Adapter.foodViewHolder>{
    private List<Food> foodList;
    private Context context;
    public Food_Adapter(List<Food> foodList,Context context)
    {
        this.foodList=foodList;
        this.context=context;
    }
    @Override
    public foodViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.card_layout,viewGroup,false);
        return new foodViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return foodList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(foodViewHolder foodViewHolder, int i) {
        Food food=foodList.get(i);
        foodViewHolder.txtName.setText(food.getTxtName());
        foodViewHolder.txtItems.setText(food.getItems());
        foodViewHolder.txtId.setText(Integer.toString(food.getTxtid()));


       foodViewHolder.txtImage.setImageResource(food.getConverted_image());




    }
//food.getTxtImage()


    public static class foodViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected TextView txtName;
        protected TextView txtItems;
        protected ImageView txtImage;
        protected TextView  txtId;

        public foodViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            txtName=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            txtItems=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtItems);
            txtImage=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.card_thumbnail);
            txtId=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtid);

        }
    }


}
```

the way I show the card:

```
 public void show_card()
    {
        RecyclerView reclist=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.cardList);
        reclist.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        reclist.setLayoutManager(llm);
        Food_Adapter fa=new Food_Adapter(Configure_bank(),this);
        reclist.setAdapter(fa);
    }
```

and my card layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:onClick="show_details"
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    android:background="@color/colorlighter"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_second">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:background="@color/colorlighter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:background="@drawable/xml_rounded_corner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:id="@+id/header"
            >
            <TextView
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/txtName"
                android:background="@drawable/xml_header_background"
                android:textStyle="bold"

                />

        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/itemcontainer"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/card_thumbnail"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

            >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="مواد مورد نیاز:"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
            android:id="@+id/itemid"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@+id/itemid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtItems"

            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"


            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/card_thumbnail"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:src="@drawable/z8"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"

            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/txtid"

            />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: 15MB on disk? They may be a lot bigger in memory, especially if automatic scaling happens.

Comment: 18662412 ~ 2160x2160 image .... why you need so big image? ... as @SamiKuhmonen wrote ... the size on the disk doesn't matter, Bitmap always take `W*H*pixelSize` (where pixelSize normally(ARGB_8888) is 4 bytes)

Comment: I need to show the pic in highest quality

Comment: @Sarah can you share the Food class.

Comment: No you don't need highest quality - ImageView's width is 120dp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Picasso Library, by adding this in your **gradle dependency**
  `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`

```
Picasso
 .with(getActivity())
 .load(mostPopular)
 .get("your_image")
 .fit()
 .into("your_imageview");
```

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need such size image. Just use Picasso for loading and resizing images, for example:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
     Picasso.with(context)
             .load(itemList.get(position).getLink())
             .error(R.drawable.error_image)
             .placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation)
             .into(holder.image);
             .into(new Target() {
                 @Override
                 public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                     int targetWidth = parentWidth / 2;
                     float ratio = (float) bitmap.getHeight() / (float) bitmap.getWidth();
                     float heightFloat = ((float) targetWidth) * ratio;

                     final android.view.ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams
                             = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) holder.image.getLayoutParams();

                     layoutParams.height = (int) heightFloat;
                     layoutParams.width = (int) targetWidth;
                     holder.image.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                     holder.image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                 }
             });
 }
```

Thus, you can get rid of the OutOfMemory problem.

Comment: The image is in resource folder (txtImage.setImageResource) not from URL, It's better to take a close look of question.

Comment: @Alexander i think that there is no need for "`.into(new Target() {...})`" as Picasso would resize automatically to fit the ImageView

Comment: @Alexander, Yes you are right. Need a small edit in your post :)